# ifelse not working in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following variables:

```
a              
welcome       
put to
look at
sorted for
```

I want to search strings in:

```
if have string "come" then b="home"
if have string "to" then b="where"
if have string "sorted" then b="done"
if have string "look" then b="great"
```

Output

```
a              b
welcome        home      
put to         where
look at        great
sorted for     done
```

I tried below code.

```
let$b <- ifelse(grepl("come", let$a), "home",
         ifelse(grepl("to", let$a), "where", 
         ifelse(grepl("sorted", let$a), "done",
         ifelse(grepl("look", let$a), "great","")))
```

The code above is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the column 'a' to be `factor` class.  If that is the case, convert the column to `character` class and then apply the code

```
let$a <- as.character(let$a)
let$b <- ifelse(grepl("come", let$a), "home",
         ifelse(grepl("to", let$a), "where", 
         ifelse(grepl("sorted", let$a), "done",
         ifelse(grepl("look", let$a), "great",""))))
let$b
#[1] "home"  "where" "great" "done"
```

Also, we could avoid the nested `ifelse` by creating `vector` of patterns ('pat') and replacements ('repl'), loop through the 'pat', get the numeric index of matching pattern in the 'a' column with `grep` and use that to get the corresponding 'repl'.

```
pat <- c("come", "to", "sorted", "look")
repl <- c("home", "where", "done", "great")
let$b <- repl[sapply(pat, grep, let$a)]
let$b
#[1] "home"  "where" "great" "done"
```

Comment: There is typo .. needed one more `)` in ifelse

Comment: What to do if we have / in the search category

Comment: what if have one more row in variable a "sorted /from". I want to look for both "sorted  /from" and "sorted for" then b =both

Comment: let$b <- ifelse(grepl("come", let$a), "home",
         ifelse(grepl("to", let$a), "where", 
         ifelse(grepl("sorted", let$a), "done",
         ifelse(grepl("look", let$a), "great",                                                                                              ifelse(grepl("sorted/from", let$a,fixed =TRUE) & grepl("sortedfor", let$a,fixed =TRUE), "both","")))))

Comment: @12345 Try `pat <- c("come", "to", "look", "sorted for", "sorted /from"); repl <- c("home", "where", "great", "both", "both");repl[sapply(pat, grep, let$a)]`

Comment: I need to give "and" condition also in this scenario

Comment: @12345 Based on the logic, I guess you want to find strings "sorted for" or "sorted /from" to be changed to "both".  In that case, the above version works.  Or if you have a string `"sorted for sorted /from" in the same string, may be `&` is needed

Comment: @12345 I didn't get your comment

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this here with the hope it helps. Another possibility for an ifelse statement not working, which caused me to find this page, is a trailing blank.

This is obvious, but note when viewing the variable in a dataframe, even highlighting it to see what is occupying the cell space, RStudio (I am using Version 1.0.153) does not show the trailing space.

Using paste(df$var) will show spaces though. Also, you can use strip.white=TRUE when your read in the data or df$var <- trim(df$var) to trim it.